# How do I get the output of a command run by QProcess in PySide?

Tags: python, qt, python-3.x, pyside, qprocess

I would like to know how I can capture the output of a command run by QProcess in PySide so that it can be displayed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ended up using this:

```
  # Create runner
  self.runner = QProcess(self)
  # Make sure newInfo gets all output
  self.runner.readyReadStandardError.connect(self.newErrInfo)
  # Run the command
  self.runner.start(command)
  # Once it's started set message to Converting
  self.parentWidget().statusBar().showMessage("Converting.")
```

Then later in the class:

```
def newErrInfo(self):
  newString = str(self.runner.readAllStandardError())
  print(newString, end=" ")
```

readAllStandardOutput() also works for stdout

Answer (score 2):

```
 QProcess qp;
 qp.start("Yourcode");
 qp.waitForFinished();
 qDebug() << "qp:" << qp.readAll();
```

For Reading live you can use functions like [canReadLine()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qprocess.html#canReadLine),[readyread()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qiodevice.html#readyRead),[waitforreadyread()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qprocess.html#waitForReadyRead) and [waitforbyteswritten()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qprocess.html#waitForBytesWritten).

Use these functions in [signal-slot](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/signalsandslots.html) mechanism for capturing data live.

Comment: No, not after the command has finished running. I mean as the command is running.

Comment: Thank you. I think I've found another answer, though.